# WSO2 IoTS APIMClientOAuthException: failed to retrieve oauth token using jwt

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have uploaded `WSO2 IoTS 3.1.0` to my remote virtual machine with static IP address.

I have unzipped `zip` file then run `sudo ./change-ip.sh`

In first step I have entered `localhost`

In second step I have entered `my_own_ip_address`

Then my hostname is `my_own_ip_address`

When I launch IoT Server and open device management then I login where it shows me this page:

[image: Error page]

When I try to open any other page and even try to logout it redirects me to this page.

My logs shows this:

```
TID[-1234] [IoT] [2017-09-09 08:32:30,079] ERROR {auth-module} - 
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.integration.client.exception.APIMClientOAuthException: failed to retrieve oauth token using jwt 

org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754) 
org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148) 
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225) 
org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:85)
```

It shows that there is an error in jaggery JS.

What did I miss?

Comment: Please explain downvoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason for the issue could be that you are having a DNS entry against that IP in /etc/hosts file. Please make sure that your /etc/hosts file does not contain any DNS entry pointing your IP to a hostname. When WSO2 IoT Server tries to resolve DNS to call the endpoints, the first thing it looks at is your local DNS setting. If your IP is pointing to a hostname, it takes that host name as the server hostname. And when IoT server tries to verify the common name of the SSL certificate, it gets conflicting information. This leads to hostname verification fail issue. And that could result in JWT token failure as it cannot access the endpoints.

Similar issue was discussed [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-iots/issues/1396)

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same issue, as mentioned in the link in the above comment. And the guy who solved it mentioned that my he mapped his ip to localhost but you are saying that IP should not be mapped to localhost.

Comment: Can you please clarify?

Comment: Yes, Because when you have IP mapped to localhost, and you have run the change-ip.sh scripts, the server is configured with the IP. When the server tries to resolve the IP and finds out, that there is a matching hostname for that. And IoT server has backend APIs which are exposed. So when a http client tries to call the backend and tries to verify the common name of the SSL certificate, it is given both IP and the hostname. This error happens when trying to call APIs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But how should I solve it , I tried mapping my local IP to the localhost  but it still won't work. Any suggestions you can provide?

Comment: I have run the change-ip.sh scripts and now I have tried both ways by mapping my IP to localhost and by removing the mapping as well. it is still not working.

Comment: Can you please follow these steps to enable debug logs?

Go to the IOT_HOME/conf/log4j.properties file.
Uncomment the following
#log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.feign=DEBUG

Comment the following
log4j.category.org.apache.synapse=WARN

Then restart the IoT server and try to login to the devicemgt application. And check the log file in IoT_Home/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log and attach the error.

Comment: Hi , this is the error that is in my log file:TID: [-1] [] [2017-10-12 21:49:13,899] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} -  I/O error: Host name verification failed for host : vm-0e2d9174-fb03-4fc4-8e55-ba675b7a795f.public.cloudvps.com {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler}
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Host name verification failed for host : vm-0e2d9174-fb03-4fc4-8e55-ba675b7a795f.public.cloudvps.comat org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.ClientSSLSetupHandler.verify(ClientSSLSetupHandler.java:171)at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doH

Comment: And this is my /etc/hosts file:127.0.0.1       cvpslnx04
#127.0.0.1 localhost
#127.0.1.1 ubuntu.cloudvps ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Comment: Add this to /etc/hosts file. ----- 
127.0.0.1 vm-0e2d9174-fb03-4fc4-8e55-ba675b7a795f.public.cloudvps.com  -----

It is because your machine name cannot be resolved. This should fix your issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot the solution worked. I was able to open it and enroll my android device with it. But devicemgmt portal is not showing the other features of the device like memory , battery , location and other stuff. All ports are open and there are no errors in carbon log as well, do u have any idea or tip what might be off?

Comment: It might take a few minutes to retrieve those pieces of information from the device. As default communication mechanism of Android devices with the WSO2 IoT server is polling at one minute.

Comment: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: i (/devicemgt/lib/utils.js#386) {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager}
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: i (/devicemgt/lib/utils.js#386)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)