# WSO2 IOT APIMClientOAuthException whene logged in device management in Docker containers

Tags: docker, wso2, jwt, wso2-iot, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to install **WSO2 IoT server** (version 3.3.0) on an instance of AWS (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS) using **docker** (https://github.com/wso2-attic/docker-iot) , Then I have run **change-ip.sh** script in order to change ip addresses for redirections.
I have changed localhost to my own static ip address.

After changing complete I have tried to login to **device management console**. However it throws me this error but **in publisher i can Access**

```
 ERROR {auth-module} -  org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.integration.client.exception.APIMClientOAuthException: failed to retrieve oauth token using jwt
```

i activeted debug logs. in IOT_HOME/conf/log4j.properties file

Uncomment the following
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG

log4j.logger.feign=DEBUG

Comment the following

log4j.category.org.apache.synapse=WARN

the results in attached file

https://github.com/wso2/product-iots/files/2977974/wso2carbon.log

my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

the hosts of dokcer container

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.4      wso2iot-server
```

it is connected to this issuses

[WSO2 IoTS APIMClientOAuthException: failed to retrieve oauth token using jwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128761/wso2-iots-apimclientoauthexception-failed-to-retrieve-oauth-token-using-jwt)

https://github.com/wso2/product-iots/issues/1396

any suggestion please?

Comment: Did you allow the inbound connection for port 8243 in the security group and subnet?

Comment: Yes I have allowed the inbound connection for all ports @Wey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is related to the HTTPS gateway port: 8243, when starting container according to the file [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/wso2-attic/docker-iot/blob/master/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml) it only exposes the port 9443 so you have to add the port 8243 to be able to access from the outside, that's why it works with localhost and after the change with the ip address it generates the error.

So I saved a new container image after changing the ip address with this commande

```
docker commit a69f82f5eb71 wso2iot-server: 3.3.1
```

and I started the image with the addition of port 8243

```
docker run -p 8243: 8243 -p 8280: 8280 -p 9443: 9443 wso2iot-server: 3.3.1
```

thank you [@Geeth Munasinghe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8465139/geeth-munasinghe) for your help